# ngFor only displays the first item in array

Tags: angular

I have a CATEGORY Array in my MongoDB database. i am fetching data from that and when i'm logging it on console it shows all the array data.
but when i'm putting it on the template with *ngFor, it only shows the first one. why ?

this is the template :

```
<label for="categoryName">Category Name</label>        
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Choose Category or Search..." name="categoryName" formControlName="categoryName" list="categorys" id="categoryName">
<datalist id="categorys" *ngFor="let category of categorys">
    <option value="{{category.categoryName}}">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Can you share us categorys array values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it as follows, **`ngFor`** should be on the option rather than on **`dataList`**

```
<datalist id="categories">
    <option *ngFor="let one of categoryList" value="{{one.categoryName}}"> 
    </option>
</datalist>
```